# How to pass multiple API call response to frontend and loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api, promise

I'm new to javascript, tried to find an answer online, but stuck here.

Trying to use Google Places API to get the data for multiple locations with a "Promise" function and then extract only "reviews" section for all locations.
After I render the results to frontend, I get:

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

If I console.log(results), I can see the results in the terminal, but only get multiple [object Object] in the frontend.

**app.js FILE:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//APP CONFIG
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// fakes request
function request(url, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(null, 200, `{"Search": "success for ${url}" }`), 200)
}


let locations = ['ChIJd5X4zalZwokR8HwFrpqhZTM', 'ChIJUQgmLP5YwokRaXhfzBfk0wY', 'ChIJ34UGSqNZwokR8PYj2UiNZ2k']

// promisesArray will hold all the promises created in map()
app.get("/resultspage", function(req, res){
  let promisesArray = locations.map(location => {
  // make a new promise for each element of cities
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=APIKEYHERE&placeid=' + location
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      var data = JSON.parse(body)
      var results = data.result.reviews;
      // resolve once we have some data
      resolve(results);
    });
  })
})
Promise.all(promisesArray)
  .then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
      res.render("resultspage", {data: results});
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)

  })
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("app has started!!");
});
```

**resultspage.ejs FILE**

```
<h1>Results Page</h1>

<%= data %>
```

Here is a link to Google Place Details webpage:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Thanks!

Comment: I think you just need to "pack it out again" with JSON.stringify in your frontend.

Comment: thanks. if I use JSON, I get messy text, like in the link below:
https://textuploader.com/d7sqp

Comment: thanks. if I use 

<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>

, I get messy text, like in the link below:
https://textuploader.com/d7sqp

so it is basically one array with 3 arrays inside and each of these arrays has 5 objects. 
if I need to extract only author_name from each review for each of 3 locations (total 15 author names), what code should I use in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
<%= data %>
```

EJS is expecting a string in between the two brackets. You've passed it instead an array of objects, which was stringified to produce what you see. Instead, you might try unpacking this until you put the fields you want into one giant string:

```
<%= data.map(review => review.author_name).join(',') %>
```

(Or, naturally, you can make my map-and-join function more complicated to add HTML tags and styling.)

Comment: thank you
i played around with your advice and i think i should be able to figure it out. Used this code:
<% for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ %>
    <li><%= data.map(reviews => reviews[i].text ).join(' , ') %></li></p>
<% } %>

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) instead of converting callback to Promise.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

app.get("/resultspage", function (req, res) {
    Promise.all(locations.map(location => rp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=APIKEYHERE&placeid=' + location)))
        .then(function (results) {
            results = results.map(result => {
                var data = JSON.parse(body)
                return data.result.reviews;
            });
            console.log(results)
            res.render("resultspage", {
                data: JSON.stringify(results)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
})
```